# WP: Как передать Post данные на другую страницу через код?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Есть такая форма:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">

 . . .
</form>
```

По нажатию на submit, post данные отправляются через js так:

```
let formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('action', 'action_name');
formData.append('product_1', values[0]);

//Сама отправка
let response = await fetch('/wp-admin/admin-post.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});

//Затем редирект
if (response.ok) {
    window.location.href = '/ru/order-success/';
```

Далее сам заказ обрабатывается в **functions.php** и в процессе создаёт xml файл

```php
function custom_action_name(){
    include ('form/order.php');
}
```

Мне нужно теперь чтобы эти post данные передались на страницу /ru/order-success/
Как это можно сделать из php (с файла form/order.php)?

Курлом не могу получить пост данные на странице.

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'domain.com/ru/order-success/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('key_1' => 'val_1','key_2' => 'val_2'),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: вам нужно передать id заказа в ответ и потом редиректить на страницу success-order с get параметром в значении которого будет этот id и уже по наличию id возвращать данные о заказе

Comment: В таком случае любой пользователь сможет ввести любой айди в гет параметр и получить сообщение об успешном заказе.

Comment: можно передать id и уникальный хеш состоящий например из id и соли, и возвращать данные о заказе если есть закза с таким id и хеширование ключи идентичны

Comment: @Konstantin пока вы не научитесь пользоваться nonce, так и будет. И с POST параметрами тоже.

Comment: @DarthKYL не надо художественной самодеятельности. Используйте nonce.